# If $f^{3}$ is integrable, do we have $f^2$ integrable?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $f$ is non-negative measurable function on $E$. If $f^{3}$ is integrable, then is $f^2$ integrable?

I think it's false, but I couldn't find a counterexample.

Comment: On a finite measure space, the $L^p$ spaces are downward-closed. That means that if $p,q, \in [1,\infty]$ with $q \leq p$, then $L^p(E) \subset L^q(E)$ for $\mu(E) < \infty$. Therefore, in your case, if $p = 3$ and $q = 2$, then $L^3(E) \subset L^2(E)$. You can use Hölder's inequality to prove this.

Comment: @Seh-kai Thanks. I read the Holder's inequality. I guess $f$ integrable does not guarantee $f^2$ integrable? Am I right?

Comment: right. Take $1/ \sqrt{x}$ over $(0,1)$ as a counterexample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p=\frac 3 2$ and $q=3$ then $\frac 1 p+\frac 1 q=1$. Hence, by Holder's inequality,  $\int f^{2} =\int (f^{2})  (1)\leq (\int (f^{2})^{p})^{1/p} (\int 1^{q})^{1/q} =(\int (|f|^{3})^{2/3} (\mu (X))^{1/3}<\infty$